# Why say "of x's" instead of "of x"?

Tags: phrase-usage, possessives, double-possessives

I have often heard people say "x of his" or "x of mine". But since *his* and *mine* point out ownership, isn't using "of" here doubles that ownership? Wouldn't it be more appropriate to say "x of him" or "x of them" etc.?

Example:

> I was a good friend **of your dad's**. He told me all about you`

Comment: That's just English. In languages close to English (Arguably, English has no close languages), for example Dutch, it would be a pleonasm, and therefore invalid grammar.

Comment: Here's a closely related question on ELL - [*Why is it usually “friend of his”, but no possessive apostrophe with “friend of Peter”?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both

> A friend of your dad

and

> A friend of your dad's

are valid (at least in British English).

I *think* this only works when we are talking about one or more particular members of some group. For example, Pete may have many friends, so we can say

> I met Mary, who is a friend of Pete's.

to mean the same as "I met Mary, one of Pete's friends". But assuming Pete has only one mother, we could say

> I met Mary, who is the mother of Pete.

but we could not say

> I met Mary, who is the mother of Pete's.

It might help to think of "a friend of Pete's" as an abbreviation for "a friend of Pete's friends", that is "someone who is one of Pete's friends".

EDIT: CopperKettle's 'picture' examples also provide a good case for the use of this construction!

Comment: Yes, I'm sure you're correct about that. Nice observation

Answer (score 7):

> I was a good friend of your **dad's**.

We can remodel this sentence into

> I was your **dad's** good friend.
>   - "Oh, when I'll write you down im my cell phone contact list as "**Dad's friend**".

Had we used the simple form **dad** instead of the "[Saxon genitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive)" **dad's**, we would've wound up with:

> I was your **dad** good friend.
>   - "Oh, when I'll write you down im my cell phone contact list as "**Dad friend**".

The wish to retain the "possessive form" in whatever construction it is used is probably the reason we (sometimes) use "friend of your dad's".

Oh, and there is a nice explanation at ELU SE's tag page for "[Double Genitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/double-genitive/info)":

> [..] This produces opposing pairs of contrasting meaning, the simple form first and then the doubled form second with further added nuance of ownership:
>
> - *a picture of **me***   vs.   *a picture of **mine***
> - *a picture of **Sam***   vs.   *a picture of **Sam’s***
> - *a picture of the **town***   vs.   *a picture of the **town’s***
>
> In the first of each pair above, the painting depicts a person or a town, whereas in the second, the painting is actually owned by a person or a town and says nothing about the subject depicted.

Comment: Note that some linguists would prefer not to call this a "double genitive", since that gives the same name to the *'s* and *of* constructions even though they're quite different.

Comment: Thanks for your observation, @snailboat. I've found that this construction is indeed seen by some linguists as "[partitive genitive or an appositive genitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm#Types_of_syntactic_pleonasm)".

Answer (score 0):

I would actually agree with you since "mine" is, in fact, showing ownership. Example: "Why did you eat my cheesecake?" I screeched. "That was supposed to be mine!"