# If "a car of my friend" is incorrect, does this mean that "a car of one of my friends" is incorrect too?

Tags: possessives, double-possessives

As far as I know:
**(1)** *my friend's car* - correct
**(2)** *a car of my friend's* - correct
**(3)** *a car of my friend* - incorrect

I'm curious about whether the correctness will remain the same if I add "*one of*":
**(4)** *one of my friends' car* - Is it still correct?
**(5)** *a car of one of my friends'* - Is it still correct?
**(6)** *a car of one of my friends* - Is it still incorrect?

(The question is about whether "one of" affects the genitive.)

an update:
I wrote "*a car of my friend*" is incorrect because:
[forum.wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-car-of-johns-john.3588025/post-18259444): the sentence "*That's a car of John*." is incorrect.
Therefore, I think, the sentence "*That's a car of my friend*." is incorrect too.
Therefore, I'm inferring, the phrase "*a car of my friend*" is an incorrect phrase.

Comment: Why use a possessive in 5)? A car of one of my friends. There is no possessive there. A car of my friend was entered in the race.

Comment: You are the OP. There is no end of the OP.

Comment: @Lambie You wrote the sentence "_A car of my friend was entered in the race_." is correct. I made an update at the end of the original post. There is the sentence "_That's a car of my friend_." which is incorrect. Why is the phrase "_a car of my friend_" in your sentence correct and in mine is not? Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing **intrinsically wrong with**: a car of my friend, which is why I provided the example in my first comment but the fact is we'd generally use: my friend's car in most cases.

Comment: 1 is correct. 2 is **incorrect**. 3 is **correct** but not idiomatic. Beyond that, "my friend's car" avoids trying to say you have a lot of friends.

Comment: What Lambie said (there's nothing intrinsically wrong with: ***a car of my friend***). It's just that we normally say ***my friend's car***. Also note that "double possessive" usages are common in English. See [Why say "of x's" instead of "of x"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38278/why-say-of-xs-instead-of-of-x)

Comment: Technically correct or not, (4), (5) and (6) all sound a bit unnatural.  In real life we would say something like "a car belonging to one of my friends" or "John's car (that's one of my friends)".